# Do PokerStars take a cut when you cash out

Tags: online

I want to start playing Real money poker on PokerStars.
I'm pretty sure PokerStars takes a cut on every pot.

Do they take a percentage or a cut when you cash out or to your bank account or card?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they don't take a cut of anything you cash in or out. They make their money from something called *rake*.

In a cash game they'll usually take 2-5% if I recall correctly, up to X amount of dollars (it caps at some point). In tournaments a portion of your buy-in will be rake. For instance, consider the $1.10 micro-stakes big field multi-table tournaments on Pokerstars. $1 goes towards the tournament prize pool, $0.10, the rake, goes to PokerStars.

Note that they aren't alone in this regard. Live, brick and mortar casinos do this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, they do now, a foreign exchange fee of 2.5%

Comment: Can you provide a link as to where you got that information from ?

Comment: http://www.pokernews.com/news/2014/10/are-new-currency-fees-at-pokerstars-part-of-bigger-changes-19649.htm